# Problemas con $_SESSION

Tags: php, html

Buenas esta es mi primera interacción en este sitio, mi inconveniente es porque creo un login y creo mi **Session** pero al pasar a la pagina siguiente no me muestra ningún dato de la **Session** pero ya confirme que si conecta con la base de datos, es la primera vez que uso plantillas así que no se si podría ser eso.

Login.php (Cabe de notar estoy usando la **Sesion 5** y el script es solo para verificar y este funciona correctamente)

```
 if ($_POST)
    {
      include("abrir_conexion.php");
            $ced_docv=$_POST['ced_doc'];
            $pas_docv=$_POST['pas_doc'];

  $resultados = mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT * FROM tam_doc WHERE ced_doc = $ced_docv AND pas_doc= '$pas_docv'");
  $variable = mysqli_num_rows($resultados);
$cargo = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados);

           session_start();
//METO TODOS LOS CAMPOS POR SI ACASO
            $_SESSION['cedula'] = $cargo['ced_doc'];
            $_SESSION['nombre'] =$cargo['no1_doc'];
            $_SESSION['nombre2'] =$cargo['no2_doc'];
            $_SESSION['apellido'] = $cargo['ap1_doc'];
            $_SESSION['apellido2'] = $cargo['ap2_doc'];
            $_SESSION['correo'] = $cargo['cor_doc'];
            $_SESSION['telefono'] = $cargo['tel_doc'];
            $_SESSION['clave'] = $cargo['pas_doc'];
            $_SESSION['estatus'] = $cargo['sta_doc'];
            $_SESSION['genero'] = $cargo['gen_doc'];
            $_SESSION['fechn'] = $cargo['fen_doc'];
            $_SESSION['discapacidad'] = $cargo['dis_doc'];
            $_SESSION['tipo'] = $cargo['ran_doc'];
---
    echo "<script>alert('Ha Iniciado Sesion Correctamente-->BIENVENIDO Admin "
    .$_SESSION['cedula']
.$_SESSION['nombre']
.$_SESSION['nombre2']
.$_SESSION['apellido']
.$_SESSION['apellido2']
.$_SESSION['correo']
.$_SESSION['telefono']
.$_SESSION['clave']
.$_SESSION['estatus']
.$_SESSION['genero']
.$_SESSION['fechn']
.$_SESSION['discapacidad'].
$_SESSION['tipo'] . $_SESSION["nombre"] . " ');location.href='SesionA.php'</script>";
```

Cada uno de los campos de la base de datos se cargan exitosa mente , pero al ir a:

SesionA.php (dice que conecta a la base de datos pero no me muestra nada en las variables de **Session**)

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  include("abrir_conexion.php"); 
  echo "<script>alert('Ha Iniciado Sesion Correctamente-->BIENVENIDO Admin "
    .$_SESSION['cedula']
    .$_SESSION['nombre']
    .$_SESSION['nombre2']
    .$_SESSION['apellido']
    .$_SESSION['apellido2']
    .$_SESSION['correo']
    .$_SESSION['telefono']
    .$_SESSION['clave']
    .$_SESSION['estatus']
    .$_SESSION['genero']
    .$_SESSION['fechn']
    .$_SESSION['discapacidad']
    .$_SESSION['tipo'] 
    .$_SESSION['nombre']. " ');
</script>";

?>
```

Todos los campos se muestran en blanco

https://mega.nz/#!BEMFnAbY!20MeiAWkN9JCmEveQcMrQZ2QeGDmMbJtf9ZMUQJWVZY

Comment: Extrae de tu código los fragmentos que se necesiten para comprender el problema y súbelos sin links externos. El hacer lo más fácilmente accesible tu código aumentará las posibilidades de que alguien responda a tu pregunta. En este sitio, además de ayudar con problemas específicos a quien lo necesita, se busca que una pregunta le sirva a futuras personas que les ocurra el mismo problema, los links externos tienden a ser inaccesibles a lo largo del tiempo, imposibilitándolo.

Comment: añade el código aquí y no desde un enlace externo, recuerda agrega solo aquellos fragmentos que sean relevantes a la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Bueno actualizo mi comentario prueba con este script eh añadido una mejor forma para que añada tus datos no se si funciona pero deberia funcionar

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['enviar']))
    {
     $servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Crea una conexion
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Comprueba la conexion a la BD
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$ced_docv=$_POST['ced_doc'];
$pas_docv=$_POST['pas_doc'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tam_doc WHERE ced_doc = $ced_docv AND pas_doc= '$pas_docv'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // datos de salida de cada fila
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['cedula'] = $row['ced_doc'];

        $cedula = $_SESSION['cedula'];

        echo "<script>alert('Ha Iniciado Sesion Correctamente-->BIENVENIDO Admin</script>"

        echo $cedula;

    }
} else {
    echo "0 Resultados";
}
$conn->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: No funciono, sigue vacio

Comment: @EsmaikellRodriguez actualice mi comentario prueba a usar ese codigo, deberia funcionar